# UIWebView with one or two features and App Store review

Tags: iphone

We have a mobile site for our existing website. We have just created an iOS application with back and forward buttons along with an activity indicator. Will it be rejected by Apple? If yes, what else we can include to get the app approved for the App Store?

Answer (score 2):

## It will be rejected

[The App Store submission guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html) say:

> **2.12**
> Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

I've also heard many stories about people who have made 'apps' for their website that might even have features like automatically logging in the user, that Apple still rejected.

Comment: it really depends on what the website is. If the Twitter iOS app were just a webview of m.twitter.com, it would probably still be accepted.

Comment: @TasosBitsios But that's Twitter.

Comment: mine is B2B app and what else we can include in our app to get it approved

Comment: @user2290189 B2B apps don't need to be approved.

Comment: I am very new to this iphone application development. I have a mobile B2B site wrapped in webview. It wont require approval from apps review team.